# iPad Air won't turn on only after charging

Tags: ipad, charging

My iPad Air works fine until I charge it.  Then it won't turn on no matter which methods I use. I've tried them all.
After two or three days of non use you can turn it on and no problems until next time I charge it. Two different Apple repair store have run diagnostics when it's working. Can't find anything wrong.

Full restore as a new iPad didn't solve the problem. Their best guess is small amount of heat from charging slightly expands battery causing it to press upon some connector. I'm using only original Apple products to charge.

Comment: Presumably it's still "on" (asleep) when it's charging, in that it's not been powered off before hand? Have you tried charging it whilst it's being used, with the screen on all the time - to see if and when it fails? Does the battery appear to be in good health - does it hold its charge well?

Comment: Battery holds charge well. Haven't tried charging it while being used. If it wakes up I'll try that approach next time I charge.